# How to save embedded object in POST call using Spring Data Rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I am using Spring 1.3.3 and I am unable to use POST call for embedded object. Getting the following error while using POST call..

Request

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{
  "student": {
    "address": {
         .....
         "zipcode": http://localhost:8082/zipcode/1,

     }
  },
  "id": 1,
  "zipcode": http://localhost:8082/zipcode/1,
  "name": "John"
 }' 'http://localhost:8082/student'
```

Response Error:

```
{
  "cause": {
    "cause": null,
    "message": "Unrecognized token 'http': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@4a12dfc; line: 3, column: 22]"
  },
  "message": "Could not read document: Unrecognized token 'http': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@4a12dfc; line: 3, column: 22]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'http': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@4a12dfc; line: 3, column: 22]"
}
```

Address.java

```
@Embeddable
public class Address {
    private String street; 
    private String city; 
    private String state;
    // getters and setters
```

Student.java

```
@Entity 
@Table(name="Student") 
@SecondaryTable(name="Student_ADDRESS",
                pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="Student_ID"))
public class Student {
    @Id private int id;
    private String name;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name="street", column=@Column(table="Student_ADDRESS")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="city", column=@Column(name="CITY", table="Student_ADDRESS")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="state", column=@Column(name="STATE", table="Student_ADDRESS")),
    })
    private Address address;
    private Zipcode zipcode;
//getters and setters
```

Zipcode.java

```
@Entity
public class Zipcode {
    @Id
    public int id;
    public String code;
}
```

How to save embedded object? Kindly provide your inputs.

Comment: kindly tell what is name of Embedded object here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It tells you that you should put "" around the urls.

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{
  "student": {
    "address": {
         .....
         "zipcode": "http://localhost:8082/zipcode/1",

     }
  },
  "id": 1,
  "zipcode": "http://localhost:8082/zipcode/1",
  "name": "John"
 }' 'http://localhost:8082/student'
```

Comment: if both associated objects exists then how we can create relation ,and put data inside composite table